# Zend Framework calls to bootstrap.php more than once

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm working with a highly developed application on Zend Framework. I have to refactor some code to fix a bunch of issues, and I've logged a debug message in bootstrap.php, to discover that bootstrap is loaded three times on every page. Is this the correct behaviour? I need to load some things just once per page, but I don't know where to execute it...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: start by looking into your page source...

Comment: I've tried that trivial start thank you

Comment: Bootstrap should only be called once per request - how are you determining how many times it is called?

Comment: I log a line in bootstrap, I read the log and see 3 same lines

Comment: check 404 requests, eg browser will try to request favicon